# Insert trigger doesnt do what i want it to do

Tags: sql, sql-server

i made a trigger which should avoid inserting a record  in the  rental 'uitlening' table if the person has an overdue payment (Boete). Unfortunately it doesnt work and i cant find the reason why. 'Boete' is an attribute of another table than rental. Can someone help me?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_uitlening]
ON [dbo].[Uitlening]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Boete decimal(10, 2);

    SET @Boete = (SELECT Boete FROM Lid WHERE LidNr = (SELECT LidNr FROM inserted));
    IF @Boete = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Uitlening
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted;
    END;
END;
```

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. What do you expect to happen when you try to assign multiple values of `Boete` selected from `Lid` to your *single* scalar variable `@Boete`?

Comment: You *assume* an `INSERT` only ever contains one row; that is untrue. An `INSERT` can affect 0+ rows. You need to explain what you are *Actually* trying to achieve with the trigger, however, for us to help you fix it.

Comment: Have you read the [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) documentation and noticed `INSTEAD OF` triggers?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning does raise a implied good point. If the `IF` evaluates to TRUE, you `INSERT` the data that has already been `INSERT`ed into the table `Uitlening` again; duplicating the row. Why do you want that?

Comment: @Larnu Correct me if im wrong, but the FOR INSTERT should avoid inserting until the IF evaluetes to true. OTherwise i dont know what AFTER INSERT should do.

Comment: `FOR INSERT` and `AFTER INSERT` are synonyms, @QuincyvanDeursen . This is stated in the documentation that AlwaysLearning previously linked.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If someone would insert multiple records, i want that each record to be checked wether the 'boete' = 0. If a record does hava a boete higher than 0, it should not be inserted.

Comment: @QuincyvanDeursen so should that row be silently discarded, or should an error be thrown? If an error is thrown, note that *all* the rows will not be inserted that were attempted, not just the one(s) that weren't valid. Can `boete` ever have a value greater than `0`? If not, why not use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: @larnu sorry for being too unclear, and thanks for helping me. 

I have an table 'rental' which has a DATE (pk), personID (fk,pk), and productID(pk, fk).
I have another table 'person' which has a PersonID(pk), and a paymentDue.

What i want is that no record in rental can be inserted if the person has a PaymentDue  thats greater than zero.

Comment: I think some sample data and expected results are needed here, @QuincyvanDeursen .

Comment: @Larnu i added a picture with the tables, data, and the query i execute. What i expect is that query would not insert the record because it doenst meet the criteria of the trigger.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you, @QuincyvanDeursen , we can't use it. Provide it in a consumable format that we can actually use (copy and paste). DDL and DML statements are by far the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to insert records into `[Rental]` of those users, who have `[PaymentDue] <= 0`. As you mentioned in your last comment:

> no record in rental can be inserted if the person has a PaymentDue
> thats **greater than zero**

And other records should be silently discarded as you didn't give a clear answer to @Larnu's question:

> should that row be silently discarded, or should an error be thrown?

If above assumptions are true, your trigger would look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_uitlening]
ON [Rental]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [Rental] ( [DATE], [personID], [productID])
    SELECT i.[DATE], i.[personID], i.[productID]
    FROM INSERTED i
    INNER JOIN Person p ON i.[personID] = p.[personID]
    WHERE p.[PaymentDue] <= 0

END;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you actually need is a cross-table constraint.

You can either do this by throwing an error in the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_uitlening]
ON [Rental]
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Person p ON i.[personID] = p.[personID]
    WHERE p.[PaymentDue] <= 0
)
    THROW 50001, 'PaymentDue is less than 0', 1;
```

---

A better solution is to utilize a trick with an indexed view. This is based on [an article by spaghettidba](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/).

We first create a dummy table of two rows

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.DummyTwoRows (dummy bit not null);
INSERT DummyTwoRows (dummy) VALUES(0),(1);
```

Then we create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwPaymentLessThanZero
WITH SCHEMBINDING  -- needs schema-binding
AS
SELECT 1 AS DummyOne
FROM dbo.Rental r
JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.personID = r.personID
CROSS JOIN dbo.DummyTwoRows dtr
WHERE p.PaymentDue <= 0;
```

This view should in theory always have no rows in it. To enforce that, we create an index on it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_vwPaymentLessThanZero
  ON dbo.vwPaymentLessThanZero (DummyOne);
```

Now if you try to add a row that qualifies for the view, it will fail with a unique violation, because the cross-join is doubling up the rows.

Note that in practice the view index takes up no space because there are never any rows in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Attention!** When you create a trigger by `FOR INSERT` or `AFTER INSERT` then don't write `insert into table select * from inserted`, because DB will insert data automatically, you can do only `ROLLBACK` this process.  But, when creating a trigger by `INSTEAD OF INSERT` then you must write `insert into table select * from inserted`, else inserting not be doing.